# авторизация в админку laravel

Tags: laravel

есть роут:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'manager', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware'=>['quest']], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@login');
});
Route::group(['prefix'=>'manager', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware'=>['auth']], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@dashboard');
});
```

если пользователь не залогинен его нужно отправить на страницу входа в админку, но он почему-то ведет на стандартную форму входа

хотя контроллер:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    //DashboardController
    public function login() {
        return view('manager.Auth.login'); //пути к файлам через точку(папка.файл)
    }
    public function dashboard() {
        return view('manager.dashboard'); //пути к файлам через точку(папка.файл)
    }
    public function userstat() {
        return view('manager.users'); //пути к файлам через точку(папка.файл)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите в app/Exceptions/Handler.php, в нем определите метод, и пропишите то, что Вам нужно, вот пример:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    return redirect(route(куда Вам нужно));
}
```

Comment: это я например делал для входа в админку, а если еще будет вход в личный кабинет? там ведь вход по разным адресам и для разных групп пользователей?

Comment: а почему не любите CMS?

Comment: Можете исходя из группы пользователя делать редирект на тот или иной логин, типо:
if($user->isAdmin){redirect}
elseif($user->isManager)...

Comment: Гадость это) Мало пространства для творчества, слишком много шаблоннов, тем и т д)

Comment: вы не поняли, ан сайте никто не авторизован, я хочу попасть в админку ввожу /manager и меня должно перекинуть на страницу login как в вопросе, и если на сайте хочу попасть в личный кабинет то принцип такой же только другая страница

Comment: Создайте для админки и фронта разные middleware, и в нем проверяйте
if(!Auth::check){redirect}
На фронтовые роуты вешаете посредника для фронта, на админку - для админки

Comment: я понял, а как в роуте это обыграть? сейчас там такая проверка 'middleware'=>['auth']

Comment: Для роутов фронта - 'middleware'=>['front_auth'] 
Для роутов админки - 'middleware'=>['admin_auth']

Comment: гляньте в ответе пожалуйста, в том ли я направлении

Answer (score 0):

смотрите, если я сделал middleware AdminAuth правильно ли я роут описал?

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'manager', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware'=>['adminauth']], function(){
    Route::get('manager/auth/login', 'DashboardController@login');
});


<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AdminAuth
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        здесь проверяю авторизован ли пользователь и его роль
    }
}
```

Comment: Не совсем. 
Route::group(['prefix'=>'manager', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware'=>['adminauth']], function(){
Тут все ваши роуты, любые, не только логин, а в  public function handle - проверка доступа и редирект
});

Comment: то есть можно и так сделать
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
  Route::get('/', function ()    {
    // Использует посредника Auth
  });

  Route::get('user/profile', function () {
    // Использует посредника Auth
  });
});
и в middleware AdminAuth уже обрабатывать каждый запрос и делать редирект на соответствующую страницу?

Comment: а можно с вами в скайпе или телеграмме попереписываться?

Comment: @manowartop - телеграмм